# Building a static library with go build for Iphone simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, go, clang, go-build

I an building a c archive in my iOS project using following:

`GOOS=ios GOARCH=arm64 CGO_ENABLED=1 SDK=iphonesimulator CGO_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" CC=`pwd`/clangwrap.sh go build -buildmode=c-archive -o libuplink.a`

Clangwrap.sh looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh

# go/clangwrap.sh

SDK_PATH=`xcrun --sdk $SDK --show-sdk-path`
CLANG=`xcrun --sdk $SDK --find clang`

if [ "$GOARCH" == "amd64" ]; then
    CARCH="x86_64"
elif [ "$GOARCH" == "arm64" ]; then
    CARCH="arm64"
fi

exec $CLANG -arch $CARCH -isysroot $SDK_PATH -mios-version-min=10.0 "$@"
```

When I link it up in XCode and attempt to run with simulator however, I can only run it on the device itself:

```
building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS ... for architecture arm64
```

How do I target the simulator for a `go build` for a static library that's used in Swift project?

Comment: Do you work with an Intel Mac? Then building for the simulator needs the corresponding architecture, namely `amd64` (so you would have to write `GOARCH=amd64` instead of `GOARCH=arm64`).

Comment: Nope my chip is Apple M1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Requirements**

- Create a static library for the iPhone simulator
- Use Apple Silicon instead of Intel simulator
- Ability to specific minimum version

**TL;DR**

You could do something similar to Xcode if you choose a simulator as run destination.

So basically use something like `-target arm64-apple-ios16.2-simulator` instead of `-arch arm64`. Also omit `-mios-version-min=10.0`, since the actual minimal version is encoded in the -target (e.g. 16.2), which takes precedence (the correct option for the simulator would be `-miphonesimulator-version-min` anyway).

Then as `CGO_LDFLAGS` also specify the `-target` option plus `-syslibroot` with the path to the SDK.

Your build scripts tweaked a bit, it might look something like this:

This specifies the simulator as the target and the minimum version is 15.

**build.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
export GOOS=ios
export GOARCH=arm64
export CGO_ENABLED=1
export SDK=iphonesimulator
export CGO_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode"
export MIN_VERSION=15

. ./target.sh

export CGO_LDFLAGS="-target ${TARGET} -syslibroot \"${SDK_PATH}\""
CC="$(pwd)/clangwrap.sh"
export CC

go build -buildmode=c-archive -o libuplink.a
```

**target.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

SDK_PATH=$(xcrun --sdk "$SDK" --show-sdk-path)
export SDK_PATH

if [ "$GOARCH" = "amd64" ]; then
    CARCH="x86_64"
elif [ "$GOARCH" = "arm64" ]; then
    CARCH="arm64"
fi

if [ "$SDK" = "iphoneos" ]; then
  export TARGET="$CARCH-apple-ios$MIN_VERSION"
elif [ "$SDK" = "iphonesimulator" ]; then
  export TARGET="$CARCH-apple-ios$MIN_VERSION-simulator"
fi
```

**clangwrap.sh**

The `clangwrap.sh` then simplifies to:

```
#!/bin/zsh

CLANG=$(xcrun --sdk "$SDK" --find clang)

exec "$CLANG" -target "$TARGET" -isysroot "$SDK_PATH" "$@"
```

---

**Details**

---

**Different SDKs**

Different SDKs must be specified for an iOS device and the iPhone simulator. You can find them next to the other platforms supported by Xcode
under `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms`.  For example, in Xcode 14.2, among others, there is an `iPhoneOS` platform with an `iPhoneOS16.2.sdk` and an `iPhoneSimulator` platform with `iPhoneSimulator16.2.sdk`.

There is this interesting post from an Apple employee in the Apple developer forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/673387#662260022

To check a generated static library to display the `load` commands, you can call:

```
otool -l libuplink.a
```

A static library generated for use with an Apple Silicon simulator should display something like the following:

```
...
Load command 1
      cmd LC_BUILD_VERSION
  cmdsize 24
 platform 7
    minos 15.0
      sdk 16.2
...
```

Note: `platform 7` denotes the simulator, `minos` the minimum deployment target, and `sdk` the actual SDK version used.

See the section in the include file `loader.h` that reads:

```
/* Known values for the above platform field. */
#define PLATFORM_UNKNOWN 0
#define PLATFORM_ANY 0xFFFFFF
#define PLATFORM_MACOS 1
#define PLATFORM_IOS 2
#define PLATFORM_TVOS 3
#define PLATFORM_WATCHOS 4
#define PLATFORM_BRIDGEOS 5
#define PLATFORM_MACCATALYST 6
#define PLATFORM_IOSSIMULATOR 7
#define PLATFORM_TVOSSIMULATOR 8
#define PLATFORM_WATCHOSSIMULATOR 9
#define PLATFORM_DRIVERKIT 10
```

You can view them yourself on your system as follows:

```
cat `xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-path`/usr/include/mach-o/loader.h
```

**Build for iPhone device**

To build a static library for the iPhone SDK, you would change this:

```
export SDK=iphoneos
```

in the `build.sh` script above.

If you tried to use this library in the simulator, it would fail with the message `building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file 'libuplink.a' for architecture arm64`.

The output of `otool -l` would read:

```
...
Load command 1
      cmd LC_BUILD_VERSION
  cmdsize 24
 platform 2
    minos 15.0
      sdk 16.2
   ntools 0
...
```

Note: `Platform 2` stands for `PLATFORM_IOS` and not for the simulator.

This will of course run perfectly on the device.

Answer (score 0):

for Stephan Schlecht answer, I should add this

```
export SDKROOT=$(xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path)
export CC=$(xcrun --sdk iphoneos -f clang)
export CXX=$(xcrun --sdk iphoneos -f clang++)
```

this will fix the error in my case:
Building for 'iOS-simulator', but linking in object file (***) built for 'macOS'

with `otool -l ***.a | grep platform`, we can see the result is:  platform 7